# Flutter: Make Video of Flutter Animations

Tags: java, android, video, flutter, flutter-animation

So, Flutter has a pretty good animation library. I want to make an animation app with flutter. So what I am thinking as of now is making pre-built animation set like bounce, ease-in, ease-out, slide in etc.

Then users chose which animation he wants to make on which image, Also can you flutter darg-drop functionality to align them but then how I make an mp4 video out of it? Only Android will work. Do we have any native(Java) approach to do it?

> Note: Screen recording will not work. What kind of animation software
>   does that? Recording animations, it will be bad for user experience